# Dependency Injection, IoC and Mocking finally explained in a simple and understandable way!

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, inversion-of-control, nerddinner

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to understand these concepts for a week now. I was really surprised when I came across with a very understandable and simple explanations of these concepts in the ASP.NET MVC NerdDinner application tutorial. I suggest this to anyone struggling to have that 'aha' moment.

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part12.htm

It's so good that I don't have any questions and won't (fingers crossed) be buried, lol.

Hopefully it will be as helpful to someone as it was to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Posting something interesting on SO is of course welcome and encouraged but since SO is a Q&A site, you are supposed to post a "real question" that you can answer yourself, as mentioned in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question*. In its current state, I'm afraid your question will get closed. So please rephrase it and post the link as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this talk really helpful for understanding how dependency injection benefits testing: ["The Clean Code Talks -- Unit Testing"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w)